# how to clean Maven repository (at Amazon S3)?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, artifacts

We're using Amazon S3 as Maven repository. With time the size of the repo is getting too big, mostly because we deploy a few snapshots per day. Is there any way to "clean" the repo by removing too old variants of the same version (`1.0-SNAPSHOT`, for example). Or maybe we can avoid them at the first place?

Comment: As mentioned by Ian, Maven repository managers like Nexus have features for purging snapshots. Without them you must maintain them yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 has a facility to automatically expire objects via what it calls [lifecycle configuration](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html), but this is quite limited - expiry is based only on the age of the objects (e.g. delete anything older than 90 days), you can't say things like "keep only the ten most recent snapshots" like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus) can do.  If you need that kind of functionality you would probably have to code it yourself as part of your snapshot deployment process.